# I have developed a web scraping code in VBA but have trouble navigating to the data I need

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

The code navigates to the page right before the page I need to get to. I need to click the 'request only' button.

The Code needs to do the following:

Access the Hertz website, Enter the pick up and drop off location, set the pick up and drop off dates. then click find a vehicle. It then needs to select a vehicle and then scrape the "One-Way fee" that appears. In its entirety I need the code to do this for all location combinations and all available car groups. for the purposes of this question, I just want help in understanding how to get to the page containing the "one-way" fee and then scrape the value into excel. I will then try and figure out how to get it to loop.

I have tried using the classname but with no luck. I had to shorten my code to fit but it seems to work still.

```
Private Sub test1()
    Dim appIE As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim a As String, b As String, c As String, d As String, e As Object, l As Object
    Dim PickUp As Object
    Dim iL As IHTMLElement                       'this declares the html object
    Dim f As IHTMLElementCollection              ' this declares the collection of html objects
    Dim post As Object, Ret As Object, entry As Object
    r = 2                                        ' sets the start row of where to input the One Way fee etc
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Hertz")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("One Way Fees")
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    With appIE
        .Navigate "https://www.Hertz.co.za"
        .Visible = True
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        Do While appIE.Busy
            DoEvents
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
        Set g = appIE.document.getElementById("return-location")
        g.Click
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        'this part sets the station in and station out cells as well as the pickup/dropoff dates
        i = 2                                    'For i = 2 To 3
        With ws
            a = 1267
            '.Cells(i, 8)
            d = 1261
            '.Cells(i, 9)
            b = "15 - May - 19"
            '.Cells(i, 10)
            c = "25 - May - 19"
            '.Cells(i, 11)
        End With
        For Each g In appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("return-location")
            If g.className = "return-location" Then
                g.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next g
        ' finds the pickup branch in html and clicks selection
        Set e = appIE.document.getElementById("pickup-depot")
        For Each O In e.Options
            If O.Value = a Then
                O.Selected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'sets the return branch and clicks the selection
        Set e = appIE.document.getElementById("return-depot")
        For Each O In e.Options
            If O.Value = d Then
                O.Selected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Set post = appIE.document.getElementsByName("pickup-pate")
        For Each post In appIE.document.getElementsByName("PickupDate")
            post.Value = b
        Next post
        ' sets the return date and clicks the button
        Set Ret = appIE.document.getElementsByName("return-date")
        For Each Ret In appIE.document.getElementsByName("return-date")
            Ret.Value = c
        Next Ret
        'Clicking find a vehicle
        For Each l In appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
            If l.className = "btn" Then
                l.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'This is the part where I would need to click the request button to select a vehicle. After this I would need the One Way fee.
        'Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can we get the website? With bootstrap and many other Javascript implementations, classNames change a lot. The class name may be different before you hover over the button. In this case you can loop all tags `getElementsByTagName("button")` and `if .innerText Like *Request Only* Then .click`. Edit: You can also use querySelector and search a single class like "vehicle__button".

Comment: @RicardoA I hope the amendment helps you to understand better my issue.

Comment: @QHarr . My code was too large to fit initially, so I removed some of the wait functions, it still seems to work however. Thank you for the links, I will go through them now.

Comment: If I enter details at that link do I then click request a vehicle? Where do I see the option for one way?

Comment: After clicking find a vehicle you need to add another `Do While app.busy` to let the website update.

Comment: ^  While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

Comment: Still can't find anything relating to one way - also seems odd given these are hire cars so who is returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure where one way is but for request only you can use classname as css selector

```
.select-vehicle
```

VBA:

```
Dim requests As Object
Set requests = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".select-vehicle")
requests.Item(1).Click '2nd in list
```

Above is nodeList of all buttons for requests you can index into

Comment: Thank you guys. I added another wait and the query selector above, it worked. The One-way fee lay in the tag:<span class="sidebar__list-left">One-Way Fee</span>. Now I just need to figure out how to get the code to loop for every available car (should be doable), then repeat the process for all available location to location combinations(abit more tricky). Thanks again

Comment: worth checking first whether prices are the same for same journeys in opposite directions i.e. a ---> b  ==   b ---> a, cos then you immediately half your inner loop iterations.

Comment: same principle may apply to vehicle type/engine size or some such in fee determination (where same price) between the same two points for different vehicles.